# Apache Reverse proxy asking for credentials for every resource of a site

Tags: apache, http, proxy, mod-proxy

Greetings I am new to apache. so please dont be so hard if this is too basic

I've been practicing by my self looking for scenarios to solve, but I have this a particular one that I can[t figure out.

I manage to set some sore of reverse proxy to forward a website that I have on an intranet.(forward it to external net throug VPN).

The thing I can't figure out is that when I acces this site through the proxy, it prompts to enter the user name an pass but it is doing this for every resource that needs to download, eg: images, style sheets,scripts every thing.

Is there a way I can configure apache confs to manage this and store some kind of cookie or cache to avoid this and enter login credentials just once.?

here is the conf I have vhost file:

```
 ProxyRequests Off
 ProxyPreserveHost Off

 <Proxy *>
     Order deny,allow
     Allow from all
 </Proxy> 

    ProxyPass    /innerLink/    http://intrasrv01:8080/sites/Home.aspx
    ProxyPassReverse /innerLink/ http://intrasrv01:8080/sites/Home.aspx

ProxyPass /  http://intrasrv01:8080/
ProxyPassReverse /  http://intrasrv01:8080/

RequestHeader unset Accept-Encoding
AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE text/html
Substitute "s|http://intrasrv01:8080/|http://172.16.27.7:8080/|ni"
```